# Can you use a network alias in a mongo configuration file when using bindIp?

Tags: mongodb, configuration, docker-compose

I am trying to get my mongodb container to listen to my API trying to connect but it won't start up. As I've understood using bindIpAll and setting it to true isn't ideal so I created a network in my compose file to get some communication between them.

Here is my configuration of that in my docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  backend:
services:
  unit:
    image: nginx/unit:1.8.0-full
    networks: 
      backend:
  database:
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    entrypoint: mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
    ports:
      - 27000:27017
    depends_on:
      - unit
    volumes: 
      - ./db/config/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
      - mongoData:/data/db/
      - mongoLog:/var/log/mongodb/
      - mongoPID:/var/run/mongodb/
    networks: 
      backend:
```

I included the unit service for understanding of the following block. In the following block I've tried to set the aliases to the networks, as well as using the actual name of the network and I haven't gotten a solution I also tried using the service's name. This is the net section of my mongo config.

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: unit #backend network defined in the docker-compose file
```

Like I mentioned the service doesn't start up, mongo gives me the following message:

```
Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
```

If I use bindIpAll in the config it all seems to work okay but as I've stated I am under the impression (perhaps incorrectly) that that's the wrong approach.

Here is my entire mongo.conf file:

```
# for documentation of all options, see:
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /data/db
  journal:
    enabled: true

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: false  # run in the background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  #bindIpAll: true
  bindIp: unit #backend network defined in the docker-compose file

security:
  authorization: "enabled"

setParameter:
  authenticationMechanisms: "SCRAM-SHA-256"
```

Comment: you didnt specify the `services` option, im surprised it came up for you

Comment: sorry I missed that, I tried to slim the conf file to just the necessary parts for this post.

Comment: maybe add your `mongod.conf` file

Comment: just added the whole config file, thanks for trying to help